# How to read a stored procedure result and write to a separate SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I built an ASP.NET MVC application that queries a SQL Server stored procedure to get data back. This is an issue as the procedure gets executed each time a call is made with the application, which inevitably slows down the application.

I am looking to create a job in SQL Server where I can read the procedure once a day and write to the database, then I will query the new table from the web app. Is it possible to create a job in SQL Server to archive this and schedule it to run once daily.

Can I get pointed into the wrote direction on this approach. I have created a job in SQL Server before, just not once that reads a procedure and write to a different database table.

Comment: Yes, possible. You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621469/sql-server-insert-stored-procedure-results-into-table-based-on-parameters

Comment: It would probably be easier and more efficient to just **cache** the results you get back from the stored procedure inside ASP.NET (using `System.Web.Caching`) and then just returns those values, instead of executing the stored procedure again